# Conserving hunger while running?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When just sprinting you last maybe a minute before you start to lose hunger, but when you do, you start to lose it fast.  While just walking looks like it saves you hunger, it is just super slow.

What is the combination of ways to conserve hunger through running?
I'm not sure, but maybe run a couple seconds then walk then run again in certain combinations?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there really is an equation for this...  Someone should peek at that code and help you out :)  -- It may be something like:  If you run no more than X blocks (like 8 or 16) then walk 1, then run again for no more than X blocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question!

As it so happens, the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger) happens to lay this all out in a nice little table:

```
Method of Transport             Exhaustion (Relates to Hunger) per block

Walking                         0.01
Sneaking                        0.005
Sprinting                       0.1
Sprinting while Jumping         0.8
```

Since this is all *per meter*, we can see that sneaking is the best. While it may be slow, it does actually conserve the most hunger. If that is too slow for you, use walking. Also, running and sprinting a little back and forth won't work too well.

Comment: Is this all traveling the same distance?

Comment: @Jason_ Yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is not what the OP asked but I'm leaving it here as an (example?) of how you can get access to different travel methods in Minecraft.

During early game, kill pigs and cows, when smelted their meat is the most efficient feeding in the game.  This supply will allow you to mostly sprint when you want to.

Towards the middle game you will want to get a saddle and tame a horse with wheat.  this will give you the prefect, speedy method of travel that you are looking for and it will hardly cost you anything in terms of food for the horse (though you will need wheat for keeping its health up).

From then on you should have an easy method of medium / long distance travel and you should have farms set up to provide you with food for short distance sprinting and health regen.

Hope this helps, if you need me to clarify then leave a comment and I'll try to get back to you :)  ~Jay

Comment: I'm actually looking for the best way to run, without food or alternate methods.  Just the best way to run, go far, and conserve hunger.  So my example run then walk then run again.

Comment: hrmmmm....   not sure really, i think im right in saying that you stop sprinting after a period of time doing so.  maybe fit that into a pattern?

Comment: @Jcraft153 The issue with sprinting being cancelled was fixed. See [MC-4839](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-4839).

Comment: Oh!  that was a bug!? I always assumed that was a tad of realism added to the game to simulate running out of stamina/breath.  oh well, thanks for pointing that out to me.  so i think maybe you want to link it to periods of time or the like so, run 2 min then walk 1 min while eating to replenish food levels, run 2 min, walk 1, etc.